# update div when commandButton is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I want to want to update a div with id="contents" when a `h:commandButton` is clicked but the complicated part is that h:commandButton is in a `c:forEach` so there are multiple `h:commandButton` s. I want the div to be refreshed whenever any of the command button is clicked. Is possible using ajax or jquery?

1)

```
<h:form>

<div id="contents">
 <c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}">  
   <h:commandButton>Click Me</h:commandButton> 
   //content
  </c:forEach>       
</div>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Post your facelet code.

Comment: I have included some of the codes form my Home.xhtml page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you button is not an AJAX button at all, so add `f:ajax` inside it:

```
<h:commandButton value="Click Me">
  <f:ajax render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Notice that I rendered hole form, as your div is actually only tag inside it. You can't update ordinary HTML tag with JSF. You can change your div to `h:panelGroup` but it is not necessary in this example.

Comment: what if I want to render a different form, not the current form in which the h:commandButton resides, then what will I write in the render `attribute`?

Comment: For example `:form2` if that is the `id` of that form. Just provide `id` on that form: `<h:form id="form2">`.